# Неприличный, непристойный и нецензурный - есть ли разница?

Tags: значение-слов

В бытовой речи оба эти слова означают примерно одно и то же. Но как-то в тексте мне попалось нечто вроде "неприличные и непристойные выражения русского языка" (я ничего специально не искала, не подумайте)))). А действительно, есть ли разница в смысле между словами "нецензурный", "неприличный" и "непристойный"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**Неприличные**" и "**непристойные**" по отношению к словам, скорее всего, - две разных степени (нейтральная и более сильно выраженная) одного и того же "неприличия". О неприличии можно говорить и в относительном смысле: самые обычные слова в отдельных ситуациях можно назвать неприличными (о верёвке в доме повешенного и т.п.)

"**Нецензурные**" - другое: это слова, которые формально не принято использовать в печати (в наше время и в электронной прессе), корректор издательства может напр. в соответствии с ведомственными правилами не пропустить какие-то авторские "находки". В разные времена отношение к тому, что нецензурно, менялось. Сейчас оно сравнительно либерально, несмотря на попытки законодательных ограничений и разъяснения от РПЦ, что сквернословие - проявление скверномыслия. Люди, имеющие выход в прессу, решают многое для себя сами, в соответствии с воспитанием и вкусом, и это разновкусие выплёскивается на телезрителей. В среде работников исключительно с высшим образованием сейчас можно услышать что угодно - не только в присутствии девушек, но и в разговоре с ними. Проблема в том, что вряд ли такие процессы обратимы.

Comment: Согласен  с  РПЦ !

Comment: >"Неприличные" и "непристойные" по отношению к словам, скорее всего, - две разных степени (нейтральная и более сильно выраженная) одного и того же "неприличия".

Интересный для меня момент.

**Возникает такой вопрос.** А что, в России действительно *"непристойно"* — это *"более сильно выраженная"*, как выше  написано, степень, чем *"неприлично"* ? 

К примеру, на Украине - это приблизительно одно и то же. Русс. слово *"неприлично"* на укр. ТВ переведут как *"непристойно"*, если это кому-нибудь интересно.

Answer (score 1):

Очень просто. Например, **жопа** не является нецензурным словом, но неприличным и непристойным *пока ещё* является.

Comment: Тут  главное  слово  -  пока.

Answer (score 0):

Неприлично - значение видно из корня слова, в присутствии лица, или прямо в лицо, лично, такого не говорят. Нынче это просто не принято "такого" говорить  в обществе.
Тема скользкая, поскольку общество бывает разным.
Непристойно, как вариант:  не пристало, тоже видно из корней слов. Непристойно - то есть не стоя близко лицом к лицу, что уже собеседнику неприятно, 
(противопоставление - достойно - держать на расстоянии).
В современном языке значение сильно поменялось от исходного.

Достоинство - не богатство и не деньги, но знание цены.
Во втором случае:  не пристало, чтоб в привычку не вошло и не стало.

Еще одно слово есть - сквернословить и соответственно скверно, скверное слово, скверное поведение. Вот это более подходяще.